# Detect characterSet of a text area using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a html page that my users can write a text and send as a text message.
I want to detect the character set of the text that they want to send.
for example my text is:
Hi there. ب
This text will detect as utf-8 in my friend Web Site.
I want to do this for myself.
can any body help?
sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't detect the encoding of the webpage and its `input` elements, you specify it. Just go with UTF-8, and whatever is pasted in will be UTF-8. To do this, either put this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

or have your web server insert this header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

UTF-8 will accomodate almost all of the characters in use today.